# Relative homology and homology of subset

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be homotopy equivalent to a point and let $A \subset X$.

 I have shown that $H_n(X,A) \cong H_{n-1} (A)$ for $n \geq 2$. I did this using the long exact sequence property in relative homology.

 Does it also hold for $n=1$. If not, what would a counterexample be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is an example.

Let $X=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2 : |x|\leq 1\}$ and $A=\{(1,0),(-1,0)\}$.
Then $A$ is a strong deformation retract of a suitable compact neighborhood of it, so that $H_n(X,A)=H_n(X/A)$.
The quotient space $X/A$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, so $H_1(X,A)=H_1(X/A)=\mathbb{Z}$.
On the other hand, $H_0(A)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ since $A$ has two connected components.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with reduced homology, then by the long exact sequence you get that $H_1(X,A)\cong H_0^{\text{#}}(A) $. But we know that $H_0^{\text{#}}(A)$ is never isomorphic to $H_0(A)$ as they have different ranks as Abelian groups (If $A$ is nonempty subspace with finitely many components and assuming we are working over the integers).

Recall that the rank of $H_0^{\text{#}}(A)$ is number of path components of $A$ minus 1 and that the rank of $H_0(A)$ is equal to the number of path components of $A$.